# Windows 8 Preview USB Boot?

Tags: windows-8-preview

I have Windows 8 Preview on an USB Flash Drive. I can boot from it and I come to an install screen. Is it possible to run Windows 8 from a USB Drive and *not* install it to the local HD (the one with Windows 7)? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the guy says in the link i provided below:

*The Full windows 8 installation to USB pen drive would eat around 12GB of space plus your own software applications. Other than that it would need temp and swap storage. You can live with 16gb pen drive but soon you’ll be choked to death.*

Rest of the instructions can be read here, given you have a sufficiently sized pen drive

http://geeknizer.com/how-to-run-windows-8-from-live-usb/#ixzz24KzADcKI

Comment: Also here: http://tech2.in.com/how-to/windows/how-to-install-windows-8-on-a-pen-drive/314452

Comment: Thanks! Good info and my purpose is just for playing with the new UI and see how it all works. I am working with a 32GB USB Stick so I will have room to play. =>

Comment: As a follow up - I went through the process with the link you provided and the link @r.tanner.f provided (both are practically the same though) and I kept getting this error `Unmountable Boot Volume`. After a bit of searching I cam across [this link](http://sergeig888.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/windows-8-windows-to-go-setup-on-windows-7/) that said if the USB is not fast enough IE USB 3 it will not work (see comments on page for the info). I am using good ole USB 2.0 and so it looks like I cannot use the USB method unless you have any other ideas.

Comment: @Lynda Looks to me like the article said that certain USB _3.0_ devices don't work. Your problem is probably something else. To be honest I never recovered from the boot process change that came with Vista, so I'm afraid I can't personally help you. Try editing your question with this new problem so it gets bumped.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no such thing as a "live" windows 8 boot disk (or USB). In order to use the OS, you must first install it.

Comment: live usb is indeed possible, but _impractical_

Comment: @Lynda it is possible!